# Android using Parse.com - missing classes on Proguard

Tags: android, parse-platform, proguard

I am using Parse on a project. The project uses my own Android library project which has the Parse jars in it. When I try to generate a signed apk, gradle gives the following issue:

> :exampleApp:proguardRelease Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find
>   superclass or interface com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody Warning:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find
>   referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
>   Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find
>   referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
>   Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find
>   referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
>   Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find
>   referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
>   Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Call Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't
>   find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Response Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Headers$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Headers$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Headers$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Headers$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Response Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
>   Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Headers$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Headers Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Headers Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Request Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Response Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Call Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't
>   find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Response Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Headers$Builder Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Headers Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Response Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$1:
>   can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$1: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Call Warning: com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$1: can't
>   find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$1: can't find referenced class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.Call Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find
>   referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find
>   referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find
>   referenced class okio.BufferedSink Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find
>   referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find
>   referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find
>   referenced class okio.BufferedSink Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find
>   referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find
>   referenced class okio.BufferedSink Warning:
>   com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient$CountingOkHttpRequestBody: can't find
>   referenced class okio.BufferedSink Warning: there were 67 unresolved
>   references to classes or interfaces.
>            You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
>            If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
>            the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
>            (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
>   :exampleApp:proguardRelease FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Edit:
Per @karama's suggestion, I added this to my proguard rules:

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient**
-keep class com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient** { *; }

# Proguard configuration for Jackson 2.x (fasterxml package instead of codehaus package)
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
```

Yet, now I get the following:

> Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find
>   referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
>   Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find
>   referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
>   Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find
>   referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
>   Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find
>   referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
>   Warning: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find
>   referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
>   Warning: there were 5 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.

If I fix it with adding:
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
When the app runs, it crashes. I saw this issue here but with no resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11249755/197127

Running the app with -dontobfuscate works fine.

Answer (score 4):

The error is not of parse sdk, it occures because of okHttp. Add below lines in your proguard.

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
```

**Edit**

for com.fasterxml.jackson add below code :

```
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
```

reference : https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/issues/19

Comment: Thanks Karan. Can I also add this for com.fasterxml.jackson ?

Comment: Thanks for the update which took me a step further. But now I have the app crash when running. I updated the question with the details.

Comment: please update your proguard by this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11032856/1944782

Comment: Hi Karan. Thanks again. But I still get the following:   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PUBLIC_ONLY
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotation(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:290)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.f.al.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit>(Unknown Source)